# A step in deriving the entire function is a polynomial is the real part of the entire function is bounded by a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand [ts375_zk26's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1647404/497335) to the question that if the real part of an entire function is bounded by a polynomial, then the function is itself a polynomial.

In the answer given by ts375_zk26, the following statement is claimed:

> Let $f(z)=u+iv=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ and $A(r)=\max _{|z|=r} u(z)$.
>   It is well-known that for $k\ge 1$
>   $$
> a_kr^k=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} u(re^{i\theta })e^{-ik\theta }d\theta .
> $$

However, I have never seen this "well-known" identity before. By applying the [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), I get
$$ a_kr^k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(re^{i\theta})e^{-ik\theta}d\theta+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}v(re^{i\theta})e^{-ik\theta}id\theta .$$
But I cannot see the reason why $$a_kr^k=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} u(re^{i\theta })e^{-ik\theta }d\theta.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula gives for $k \ge 0$
$$ \tag{1}
 a_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}} \, dz
 = \frac{1}{2 \pi r^k} \int_0^{2 \pi } f(re^{i\theta}) e^{-ik \theta} \, d\theta \, .
$$
Cauchy's integral theorem gives for $k \ge 1$
$$ \tag 2
 0 = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=r} f(z) z^{k-1} \, dz
 = \frac{1}{2 \pi r^k} \int_0^{2 \pi} f(re^{i\theta}) e^{ik \theta} \, d\theta \, .
$$

Now take the conjugate of $(2)$ and add it to $(1)$:
$$
 a_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi r^k} \int_0^{2 \pi} 2 \operatorname{Re}f(re^{i\theta}) e^{-ik \theta} \, d\theta 
$$
which is the desired formula. Similarly, one gets
$$
 a_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi r^k} \int_0^{2 \pi} 2 \operatorname{Im}f(re^{i\theta}) e^{-ik \theta} \, d\theta 
$$
by multiplying the conjugate of $(2)$ with $i$ and subtracting it from $(1)$.