# $f(z)$ is analytical function derive this form of $f'(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

$f(z)$ is analytical in $0<|z-a|<R$, and $r<R$ then prove that $$f'(a)=\frac{1}{\pi r}\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(\theta)\exp(-i\theta)d\theta$$
Where $P(\theta)$ is the imaginary part of $f(a+r\exp(i\theta))$

Using the cauchy integral formula $$f'(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz$$

We take $c$ as the circle of radius $r$ centered at $a$. this gives $z= a+r\exp(i\theta)$. We substitute above to get $$f'(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi r }\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(a+re^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}d\theta$$

I am not able to proceed beyond this.

Comment: You've substituted as if the expression reads $(z-a)^{-1},$ you should get $r^{-2} \exp(-2i\theta)$ which should cancel with one $r$.

Comment: I think the integral after choosing the contour should be $\frac1{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} f(a + r e^{i \theta}) i r^{-1} e^{-i \theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta$.

Comment: You can proceed similarly as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290900/42969.

Comment: Got it thanks .